How to fix node error after upgrading node version to 20
I have upgraded my node to version 20, and my angular 5 code is breaking because of that.
Errors that I am getting
npm info run node-sass@9.0.0 postinstall {code:0, signal:null }
npm info run node-sass@4.14.1
postinstall {code:0, signal:null }

I just realised if I remove @angular/cli
And @angular/compiler-cli
npm info run node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall {code:0, signal:null }
This line doesn’t display.
For node modules my organization is using its own antifactory.
So what I am supposed to do?
Upgrading node version to 20 is the requirement it works perfectly fine with node version 12.
Do I also have to upgrade angular code ? or just fixing these node module should be fine ?

Searching on angular official site, I found this table which says which versions of angular are compatible with which versions of node. So it looks like you have to use version 17 or higher of angular if you want to use node 20


Does npm install gets affected because of that ?
I think even though I don’t upgrade my angular npm install should run fine .. right ?

Plus if I upgrade my project would you recommend directly upgrading to angular 17 or first to 9 then 11 then 17 approach ?

Im not quiet sure, but probably it does, npm does more things that only download the dependencies. About upgrading angular, I would recomend you upgrading directly to angular latest version, it will be a lot of work to do but it doesnt make sense to upgrade to one version and then to another, since it could be that something that you migrated to the next version needs to be migrated again to the latest version. It also depends of the size of the proyect and the reason, if is to fix an specific bug or security issue, its okay to upgrade to an specific version instead of the latest

Ok thanks :) for your input I will update my answer with the fix in few days

Upgrade angular version using angular update guide.
If it's not possible, then downgrade to old version of node.
Use nvm windows to manage node versions.

Angular upgradation is something I can consider! In my org downloading lower version of node is causing issue they are sending the system to quarantine so we have decided to make the UI code compatible with Node20
